# Is there a tutorial somewhere for doing CRUD using a ListView?

Tags: asp.net, listview

This is usually found in asp.net textbooks near the start but at work we don't have any for asp.net 3.5 or higher. I've tried googling but I cannot find anything that shows how to implement CRUD using a ListView. I have added a ListView to my page and implemented the item templates etc. and what I want to do next is make it so you can edit/delete rows. The rows are like:

```
Name  Age  Height 
Bob   24   185 
Steve 25   158
```

etc.

If anyone can link me to a tutorial that will guide me through adding edit/delete buttons etc. I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

There are several:

[Walkthrough: Displaying, Paging, and Sorting Data Using the ListView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515102.aspx) and [Walkthrough: Modifying Data Using the ListView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515103.aspx) on MSDN,

and a very useful article by Scott Guthrie: [The asp:ListView control (Part 1 - Building a Product Listing Page with Clean CSS UI)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx).